# Selecting data from dataframe randomly but do not REPEAT

Tags: python, r, random, pandas

If I have a dataframe such as number from 1 to 50, then I need '`X`' sets of number, each set contains '`Y`' random numbers. And the number could not be REPEAT.

For example, `X =5 and Y=5`

```
X1 1, 8, 12, 17, 16
X2 9, 22, 45, 47, 23
X3 13, 19, 21, 34, 50
X4 46, 49, 29, 38, 11 
X5 33, 26, 14, 7, 6
```

Does anyone know how could I do this by python Pandas or random package or by R?

Comment: What about shuffling the rows (or indices) then every time you need an element for X, pop one off the shuffled result?

Comment: In R, try `matrix(sample(50, 5*5, replace=FALSE), ncol=5)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [64]:

np.random.choice(np.arange(1,51), (5,5), replace=False)
Out[64]:
array([[18, 35, 20, 39,  7],
       [27, 41, 26, 30, 14],
       [47, 23, 17, 40, 38],
       [34,  6,  3, 42, 31],
       [48, 49, 16, 15,  1]])
```

You can then pass this to the df constructor:

```
In [65]:

pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(np.arange(1,51), (5,5), replace=False))
Out[65]:
    0   1   2   3   4
0  35  41  38  50  26
1  24  34  14   2  29
2   8  43  25  17  49
3  30   5  40   6  21
4  20  11  31  33  23
```